# inline-flex element is not aligning properly

Tags: html, css

I have 3 elements (with yellow background) which count monetary amounts.

**The counters are animated each time the amount is updated, so each counter has some underlying HTML/CSS to handle the animation. Therefor the underlying CSS can NOT be changed because then the animation will not work anymore**

My issue is that I can't make the counter elements with the yellow background align properly. I want them to align just beneath the label for each counter. The label has the style `padding-bottom:2px;`

The 2 first counters are a bit far from the label above

[image]

How I want to align the elements

[image]

Base structure of DOM (see full HTML in link)

```
<div id="account_monitor">
    <div class="account-monitor">
        <div class="account-monitor-label">label</div>
        <div class="amount counter" style="height: 21px">value</div>
    </div>
    <div class="account-monitor">
        <div class="account-monitor-label">label</div>
        <div class="amount counter" style="height: 21px">value</div>
    </div>
    <div class="account-monitor">
        <div class="account-monitor-label">label</div>
        <div class="amount counter" style="height: 21px">value</div>
    </div>
</div>

#account_monitor{
    display:flex;
    gap:30px;
    padding:10px;
}

.account-monitor{
    min-width:130px;
    text-align:right;
}

.account-monitor-label{
    padding-bottom:2px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:11px;
}

.counter{
    display:inline-flex;
    flex-direction:row-reverse;
    align-items:flex-end;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    background:yellow;
}

.amount{
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

You can find the complete HTML in the link

https://jsfiddle.net/a18Lmpfh/1/

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure I understand exaclty how you want to achieve the alignment, what is your end goal here, but maybe that is out of the scope of your question and my answer.

#### Solution

Check the code below.

I removed from *.counter-wheel*:

- `position: relative;`
- `flex-direction: column-reverse;`  (changed it to column)

In *.counter*:

- `align-items:flex-end;` is not needed anymore.

**Note:** I commented out the overflow-y:hidden; so it's easily visible how the alignment works.

I have the feeling though that you want different order on the numbers in a column.
If that's the case, maybe, one thought is to change the order you declare them in your HTML, consindering that the solution I provided works for you.

#### Maybe that helps too

[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**P.S.:** Generally speaking, I would avoid positioning items so strictly
*(top:0px; top:42px; top:189px; etc...)*
I bet there should be a better way to align items the way you want them to.
Usually, I see such specific positioning when creating CSS art, which in that case makes sense.

```css
#account_monitor {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.account-monitor {
  min-width: 130px;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.account-monitor-label {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.counter {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  /* align-items:flex-end; */
  /*    overflow-y:hidden; */
  background: yellow;
}

.counter.direction-negative {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.counter-wheel {
  /* position:relative; */
  display: flex;
   /* flex-direction: column-reverse; */
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.counter-wheel.direction-negative {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.counter-wheel-void {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.amount {
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="account_monitor">
  <div class="account-monitor">
    <div class="account-monitor-label">label 1</div>
    <div class="amount counter" style="height: 21px;">
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="width: 10.0156px; top: 0px;">
        <div>0</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="width: 10.0156px; top: 0px;">
        <div>0</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="top: 0px;">
        <div>,</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="width: 10.0156px; top: 0px;">
        <div>0</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="width: 10.0156px; top: 189px;">
        <div class="counter-wheel-void">0</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="width: 10.0156px; top: 42px;">
        <div class="counter-wheel-void">0</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="top: 21px;">
        <div class="counter-wheel-void">.</div>
        <div>.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="width: 10.0156px; top: 42px;">
        <div class="counter-wheel-void">0</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="account-monitor">
    <div class="account-monitor-label">label 2</div>
    <div class="amount counter" style="height: 21px;">
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="width: 10.0156px; top: 0px;">
        <div>0</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="width: 10.0156px; top: 189px;">
        <div>0</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="top: 0px;">
        <div>,</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="width: 10.0156px; top: 42px;">
        <div>0</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="width: 10.0156px; top: 147px;">
        <div class="counter-wheel-void">0</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="width: 10.0156px; top: 63px;">
        <div class="counter-wheel-void">0</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="top: 21px;">
        <div class="counter-wheel-void">.</div>
        <div>.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="width: 10.0156px; top: 42px;">
        <div class="counter-wheel-void">0</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="width: 10.0156px; top: 21px;">
        <div class="counter-wheel-void">0</div>
        <div>1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="account-monitor">
    <div class="account-monitor-label">label 3</div>
    <div class="amount counter" style="height: 21px;">
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="width: 10.0156px; top: 0px;">
        <div>0</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="width: 10.0156px; top: 0px;">
        <div>0</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="top: 0px;">
        <div>,</div>
      </div>
      <div class="counter-wheel" style="width: 10.0156px; top: 0px;">
        <div>0</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can not change the underlying HTML because then my animation will not work. I just want the yellow elements to align in the same way.. 2px below the label element

Answer (score -1):

```css
#account_monitor{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  gap:30px;
  padding:10px;
}
.counter{
  background: yellow;
}
```

seems like you only need this much to properly align the boxes.

Comment: If you remove flex from the counter element my animation will not work anymore